# Dropper/hopper chains not working as expected

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have made the following circuit:

[image]

I'm expecting to move the item one dropper ahead everytime I send a pulse, eventually making it back to the first dropper after 4 pulses. According to the outputs, however, it's jumping back and forth between the left 2 droppers.

[image]

The image above is a 3-state machine that I'm actually trying to build. This works as intended, but only in this exact configuration. If I switch the right hopper and dropper (updating their directions), or build the circuit elsewhere in my world with the same orientation, the same issue of skipping the right side occurs.

Can someone explain this behaviour to me, and give me a way to achieve the desired behaviour (consistently)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant dropper lines in are possible in Minecraft. That is most likely what is happening here. When you activate the redstone dust, it powers the droppers in certain order (this order is dependent on the location and orientation of your contraption – this is one of the reasons you should not use dust for this); in this case, the order seems to be something along the lines of: bottom left, top left, bottom right, top right. In this order the droppers schedule to 2 game ticks later (1 redstone tick) pass their items.

It is not possible to power the four droppers in the same order such that no instant dropper lines are formed; one of them will always have one that is powered after it in front of it.

You could try alternating the update order or using 5 droppers (the `43215` will have one instant dropper pair in it, acting like a four state machine). Another option would be to simply not use droppers at all.